# Kafka : Generating unique IDs for strings across partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to asses if Kafka could be used to scale-out our current solution.
I can identify partitions easily. Currently, the requirement is there to be 1500 partitions, each having 1-2 events per second, but future might go as high as 10000 partitions.

But there is one part of our solution which I don't know how would be solved in Kafka.
The problem is that each message contains a string and I want to assign a unique ID to each string across the whole topic. So same strings have the same ID while different strings have different IDs. The IDs don't need to be sequential, nor do they need to be always-growing.

The IDs will then be used down-stream as unique keys to identify those strings. The strings can be hundreds of characters long, so I don't think they would make efficient keys.

More advanced usage would be where messages might have different "kinds" of strings, so there would be multiple unique sequences of IDs. And messages will contain only some of those kinds depending on the type of the message.

Another advanced usage would be that the values are not strings, but structures and if two structures are same would be some more elaborate rule, like if PropA is equal, then structures are equal, if not, then structures are equal if PropB is equal.

To illustrate the problem: Each partition is a computer in a network. Each event is action on the computer. Events need to be ordered per-computer so that events that change the state of the computer (eg. user logged in) can affect other types of events, and ordering is critical for that. Eg. the user opened an application, a file is written, a flash drive is inserted, etc.. And I need each application, file,  flash drive, or many others to have unique identifiers across all computers. This is then used to calculate statistics down-stream. And sometimes, an event can have multiple of those, eg. operation on a specific file on the specific flash drive.

Comment: So you want the same strings should persist in the same partition? If I understood your problem correctly or else let me know.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @RamanMishra No. The strings are part of bigger event and won't be key to partitions.

Comment: @cricket_007 How to implement my requirements in a way that scales.

Comment: Adding brokers is what scales, not adding partitions to a limited set of machines

Comment: @cricket_007 Let me rewrord it "How to implement my requirements in a way that can be run in parallel on multiple brokers". I can implement it in trivial way, but then it would be forced to run on single broker (or would behave as such).

Comment: Okay, so if you set a null key, then messages will round-robin over all partitions. If you generate some key value at random UUIDs, then you potentially run the risk of "hot partitions", where your data gets skewed onto those. Similarly, if you defined your own partitioner class. If you care about tracking messages by the key, then you can guarantee ordering within a partition for matching keys. Again, scalability is more from # of producers and hardware. At some point, you will be CPU or network capped, and adding partitions will not help

Comment: Regarding your illustration, use multiple topics for each action type (applications, devices, files). Key the actions by the computer name, thereby generating an in-order log of all actions by type, by computer

Comment: The questions seem to be unclear, can you reword the question with a few examples?

Comment: @SudevAmbadi What is unclear about example I provided?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice post about [kafka and blockchain](https://made2591.github.io/posts/kakfa-and-blockchain). This is collective mind work and I think this could solve your IDs scalability issue. For solution refer to "Blockchain: reasons." part. All credits goes to respective authors.

- Idea is simple, yet efficient:

  - Data is hash based, with link to previous block
  - Data may be very well same hashes, links to respective blocks of types
  - Custom block-chain solution means you in control of data encoding/decoding
  - Each hash chain is self-contained, and essentially may be your process (hdd/ram/cpu/word/app etc.)
  - Each hash chain may be a message itself
- Bonus: statistics and analytics may be very well stored in block-chain, with high support for compression and replication. Consumers are pretty cheap in that context (scalability).

---

Proc:

- Unique identifier issue solved
- All records linked and thanks to kafka & blockchain highly ordered
- Data extendable
- Kafka properties applied

---

Cons:

- Encryption/Decryption is CPU intensive
- Growing level of hash calculation complexity

Problem: without problem context it's hard to approximate the limitations that need to be addressed further. However, assuming calculated solution has a finite nature you should have no issues scaling the solution in a regular way.

---

Bottom line:
Without knowledge of requirements in terms of speed/cost/quality it's hard to give a better, backed answer with working example. CPU cloud extension may be comparably cheap, data storage - depends on time for how long and what amount of data you want to store, replay-ability, etc. It's a good chunk of work. Prototype? Concept in referenced article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think the problem is so big that we would go as far as using blockchain.